# python 3.2 apache httpd.conf parse

Tags: python, apache, httpd.conf, python-3.2

I want to know if there are any good modules/libraries/tutorials/'anything that I have forgotten' to parse httpd.conf.

Specifically:
I need to be able to extract from said file several lines contained in the  tag.
This can be in either the tag itself (`<VirtualHost hereissometext>`) or between the tags itself.

Any and all help appreciated.

Greetings,

Saulius

Comment: What have you tried? This seems fairly simple using a bit of regex and pulling out lines from the file? What's the actual output that you seek?

Comment: I've tried ElementTree, xml.dom.minidom, and others.
At the moment I've written a part for my own, that basically loops line per line(file to list of strings). Since there are no nested <VirtualHost> tags, there is no problem there. 

Further a few functions to get the coordinates for the VHost tags, and a detailfunction based on the first word of the configuration.